# java web services call works with proxy, but not without

Tags: java, ssl, proxy, java-metro-framework, charles-proxy

My application makes a SOAP web service call over SSL to a remote server using Metro 2.2, which worked fine in Java 1.6.  We have recently upgraded to Java 1.7, and now the same call is failing.  The remote server reports that it is unable to parse the SOAP envelope.  I have no additional access into the remote server, other than that error message.

In an attempt to diagnose the problem, I set up the [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy, which can act as a MITM SSL proxy, and configured my app to use it.  To my surprise, the calls succeed just fine when routed through the Charles proxy.  But they continue to fail when I don't route through the proxy, and I'm at a loss as to why.

Any ideas are appreciated.